# How many people are representing the US officially in the 2018 Winter Olympics?

Tags: olympics

I was watching the opening ceremony and the announcer mentioned that there were 242 athletes representing the US in the Olympics. My question is does this represent all the trainers and coaches as well as the athletes or just the athletes. If it is just the athletes what is the total amount of US personnel involved in the Winter Olympics, in an official capacity : i.e. coaches, trainers, doctors, and any others I may not be aware of this year?

Comment: I don't think there is a credible source for the staff size, but that number is indeed just the athletes (see also [Team USA](https://www.teamusa.org/PyeongChang-2018-Olympic-Winter-Games/Team-USA/Athletes)).